# angularjs , wait for authorization result before go to next controllers

Tags: angularjs

Hello i have simple LoginService that looks like that:

```
this.notifyAuthorization = function() {
    console.log('notifyAuthorization()');

    $http({
        url: 'app/?cmd=authorization/',

    }).then(function (response) { console.log('LoginStatusResult: '); console.log(response.data);
        var data = response.data;

        if(data.hash !== undefined) {
            $rootScope.loginStatus= true;
            hash = data.hash;
        }
    });
};
```

here is the call for the service

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, LoginService) {
    LoginService.notifyAuthorization();
    console.log('notifyAuthorization Finished');
});
```

Before seeing `LoginStatusResult` i see `notifyAuthorization Finished`
and other controllers are initialized that should know the LoginStatus so how to solve this ? or is there a better practice ?
Thanks

Comment: This is because `notifyAuthorization()` is an asynchronous function, meaning that it does not block the rest of the code until it is finished. You can solve this problem using **promises**. Check out the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Answer (score 2):

Use [promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises), which are given by default by your $http function:

```
this.notifyAuthorization = function() {

    return http({ //notice the return inserted here
        url: 'app/?cmd=authorization/',

    }).then(function (response) { console.log('LoginStatusResult: '); console.log(response.data);
        var data = response.data;

        if(data.hash !== undefined) {
            $rootScope.loginState = true;
            hash = data.hash;
        }
    });
};
```

and use it properly in your app.run:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, LoginService) {       
   LoginService.notifyAuthorization().then(function(){
        $rootScope.authorized = true;; //executed after your $http request...
   });
});
```

and in your html code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-if="$root.authorized"> 
    <!-- your inner code..

         <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et                 
         malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
         feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. </p>             
    -->
</div>
```

This way, your controller will be instantiated only after the .then function has resolved

Comment: its kinda the same for me because i need to know the LoginStatus before controllers initialization

Comment: Then add a ng-if variable in your notifyAuthorization then function. see my updated answer for details.

Comment: let say i have a LoginController which i need NOT need to be called if `root.authorized` is TRUE,  by default `root.authorized` is FALSE , so it will call the LoginController and then when the Result will be received the NG-IF it will Hide the controller what can i do in this situation?